# example of CursorLoader in SqliteDatabase

Tags: android

I want to read large number of database for that i would go with loadermanager and loder and cursor loader but i have searched so much things but couldn't find out best example of it, Please if any one find example of CursorLoader with Loadermanager please provide me link or source code